# Javascript get value in attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery `.attr` in an input type so when I run this

```
console.log('name: '+$(this).attr('name'));
```

output is: `name: user_project_category[65][skill][9]`

**How can I get the 65 and 9?**

Comment: Show your jquery code.

Comment: Hi this is my code in jquery

Comment: $('.tagTeam').each(function(index){
    console.log('member id:' + $(this).val());
    console.log('name: '+$(this).attr('name'));
   });

Comment: and this is my input type attribute '<input class="form-control tagTeam" type="text" name="user_project_category['+category_id+'][skill]['+suggestion.skill_id+']" placeholder="Enter Members"/>';'

Comment: you are getting the client id

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to extract text from between the brackets into an array and then you can access the array to get the values you want, you can either extract all text between brackets or just the numbers:

```js
var yourInput = "user_project_category[65][skill][9]";
var allMatches = yourInput.match(/\[(.*?)\]/g);
console.log(allMatches[0]);
console.log(allMatches[2]);

var numberMatches = yourInput.match(/\[([0-9]*?)\]/g);
console.log(numberMatches[0]);
console.log(numberMatches[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expression or split function in JavaScript

```
var output= 'user_project_category[65][skill][9]';
output.split(/(\d+)/)[1];
output.split(/(\d+)/)[3];
```

Comment: this is not an answer to the OP this is just a suggestion better put into comment

Comment: Below 50 reputation cannot comment.

Comment: sorry for my format this what Im trying for split                                           var dataaa = $(this).attr('name');
  var info = dataaa.split("[ ]");
  alert(info);

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = "name: user_project_category[65][skill][9]";


console.log(data.split("[")[1].slice(0,-1))//use split to get 65] use slice to remove ]
console.log(data.split("[")[3].slice(0,-1))//use split to get 9] use slice to remove ]
```

1. You can use split with slice

Assuming this is not dynamic and format is the same.
for dynamic use regex

Comment: Hi! this is dynamic but still thank ypu for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Use regex.

```
var output = 'user_project_category[65][skill][9]';
var numbers = output.match(/\d+/g).map(Number);
alert(numbers);
```

output: `65,9`

Do whatever you want to do with number.

[working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shree/o8b6qokd/1/)

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comment really helpful!